# Can I change "All Songs" order in iPhone 4s Music app?

Tags: iphone, music.app

My iPhone Music collection has several albums by the same artist.  When I select that artist in the Music app I see these albums listed, & "All Songs" at the top.  When I select "All Songs" the songs are listed in alphabetical order on **track name**.

Is it possible to change the "All Songs" order to keep albums together, eg alpha on album name (or numeric on album year), & then by track number within each album?  This seems like the most likely way you'd want to play all songs by an artist, so I'm surprised it's not the default & that I can't find a way to do this.

[image: "All Songs" showing alpha on track name ordering]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this question is incredibly simple, and needs no elaboration other than enough to justify the size of the post and prevent Stack Exchange from automatically marking it as low quality or affecting it. That answer?

No, you can't. The All Songs section of an artist view, exactly like the all Songs category on iOS, is always by alphabetical title.

Answer (score 0):

Yep software not written by a music lover.
You have to create a new playlist, then select artists and your artist, then select all songs and they will be in the album order about 6 or more keystrokes